# How to DROP a HEAP index on an Azure Synapse table to improve the query performance on the table?

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse, database-indexes

We just noticed recently that some of our Azure Synapse tables are performing very slow. When we looked at the index information we saw `HEAP` indexes. We're not sure how they were formed in the first place. But after going through the microsoft documentation, I understood that HEAP indexes are formed when a table is created without a `CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE` index.

The below is an example table with `HEAP` index (as well as other indexes) from our database on Synapse (also, why are there duplicates in the `object_id` field??) :

```
object_id   index_name                                      table_name          index_type
123582548   NULL                                            daily_sales         HEAP
123582548   Cnstr_e808ee8e05c94eb39ce93c5b6abc042x          daily_sales         NONCLUSTERED
486209858   ClusteredIndex_9336ef41b4424fd0a554f6964799x77x daily_sales         CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE
486209858   Cnstr_x235c6b022b74af2be06e541281b625f          daily_sales         NONCLUSTERED
```

I want to drop these `HEAP` indexes to improve the performance but I'm unable to do so because, apparently, `HEAP` indexes don't come with a name attached (hence a `NULL` in the name). And I do need a name to drop the index as shown in the below syntax:

`DROP INDEX index_name ON { database_name.schema_name.table_name | schema_name.table_name | table_name }`

This is the first time I'm encountering a `HEAP` index and I have no idea how to handle them. So, I just want to ask the below:

MS Documentation suggests to create a `CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE` index on the table that only has a `HEAP` index. As shown in the above example, we do have `CLUSTERED` index as well on the table but still the table doesn't perform. So, I'm under the impression that dropping the `HEAP` index will improve the performance. Is this assumption even valid?

If so, is there a way to DROP the `HEAP` indexes on Synapse tables to improve the performance? How to do it?

But if dropping a `HEAP` index is not a thing, then what can I do to make sure the `HEAP` index doesn't hamper the query's performance?

At this point, the only solution we're able to look at is to backup the table data, then create a new table with a `CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE` index and then insert the data from the backup table into this new table and then drop the original table that has `HEAP` index. But, to be honest, this doesn't sound like a clean way of solving this problem and we have many tables with `HEAP` index. So, this approach is not scalable.

What's best way to solve this problem? Any help, please?

Comment: On object 123582548    you have a NONCLUSTERED index, but you need a CLUSTERED index to make sure your table is not a HEAP

Comment: A heap is not an index, it's "just a bunch of rows". Essentially it's the absence of a clustered index (either regular or columnstore). You should create a clustered index on the table (I advise a regular one unless you know otherwise). You have two entirely different tables called `daily_sales `presumably in different schemas See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/heaps-tables-without-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16 and https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/heaps-tables-without-primary-key-clustered-index/

Comment: An option to consider is recreating the existing nonclustered index as a clustered one. Also see https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/